# is database locking enabled by default in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Some frameworks are opinionated when it comes to database locking.  For example, grails orm (gorm) documents state the following:

> By default GORM classes are configured for optimistic locking

***Source***: https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#locking

I've read through some material online for rails and my understanding is that rails does not provide locking by default.

What is rails default approach to locking?

---

**NOTE**: This is NOT a question about which approach is best, it is a question to confirm rails's approach to locking.

Comment: If this question does not fit stackoverflow's requirements, and you down vote it please let me know why so that I can improve the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, I'm pretty sure that database locking is turned off in Rails. If you do want to use locking, have a look at this from the ruby on rails docs:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html

Comment: I see that rails offers optimistic locking and pessimistic locking. Is the default behaviour one of these, or no locking at all?